# Group Indexing in Informix

Tags: indexing, informix

I have a table called `hitlist`, which has 3 columns:

```
int id
long hitlisted_date
long deleted_date
```

I will be querying this table based on these columns:

```
histlisted_date (frequent)
hitlisted_date && deleted_date (frequent)
deleted_date (not frequent)
```

In this situation, what kind of index should I use?

1. Separate index on `hitlisted_date` & `deleted_date`
2. Group index on `hitlisted_date` & `deleted_date`

**UPDATE**

The table will have just 1000 - 5000 rows.
These are the query patterns that will be used.

1) hitlisted_date BETWEEN
2) hitlisted_date <
3) deleted_date = -1 and hitlisted_date <=
4) deleted_date > 0

For the above patterns, these indexes would suffice?

1. CREATE INDEX i1_hitlist ON hitlist(hitlisted_date);
2. CREATE INDEX i2_hitlist ON hitlist(deleted_date, hitlisted_date);

Comment: Note that DATE(-1) is 1899-12-30.  If everything is sufficiently recent that it isn't going to interfere, you're fine, but it wasn't so long ago that there were people older than that in general circulation.

Comment: The date columns are `long` data types (epoch time)

Comment: So they aren't DATE types.  They're INTEGER columns.   A DATE type in Informix has specific connotations.  (And 1969-12-31 23:59:59 is more recent than 1899-12-30; it may not be a problem even so, but but be cautious.)

Comment: Looks like you need to cast the LONG epochs into a DATETIME or DATE type column in order to properly do date arithmetic queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `hitlisted_date` and the combination will be used frequently, you want a composite index on the two columns with `hitlisted_date` first:

```
CREATE INDEX i1_hitlist ON hitlist(hitlisted_date, deleted_date);
```

This index can (and will) be used for queries with a suitable condition on `hitlisted_date` on its own, or for the two dates.

You may find it beneficial to have a second index on just `deleted_date`:

```
CREATE INDEX i2_hitlist ON hitlist(deleted_date);
```

This can be used for searches on just `deleted_date`.  If you sometimes do searches on a single deleted date and a range of hitlisted dates, then you might find it better to use a compound index that's the reverse of `i1_hitlist`:

```
CREATE INDEX i2_hitlist ON hitlist(deleted_date, hitlisted_date);
```

It's unlikely to be a help, but the only way to be sure is to try it and see.  It depends on your query patterns, and the actual conditions your queries use.

There's no real virtue in an index on just `hitlisted_date`; it just gets in the way of the optimizer (because it has to look at two indexes and decide which is better, and because there is more work to do as rows are inserted, updated and deleted).  It is unlikely that the hitlisted date could be a unique index.  If it could, then there'd be a separate reason for keeping the single-column index as well as the duplicates index.  (See also [Is an index on (A,B) redundant if there is an index on (A, B, C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791317/is-an-index-on-a-b-reundant-if-there-is-an-index-on-a-b-c/).)

After you change indexes, make sure the statistics are up to date (more or less automatic these days, but it used to be important), and then run queries with SET EXPLAIN on to check that the indexes are being used (and which indexes are being used).

Comment: So then why not just only create a composite index on (A,B,C)? That should cover any combination of queries?

Comment: In the cross-referenced question, there already is an index on (A, B, C); the question is would an index on just (A, B) be beneficial too.  And the answer is 'No, unless (A, B) is unique'.

Comment: Several factors: column cardinality, frequent query patterns, nrows, rowlength, static or frequent table updates, etc. determine how and which columns to index?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have updated my question with some information on the table and the indexes based on your inputs. Let me know if it looks good. Would all the 4 query patterns be served by the indexes?

Comment: For your given query patterns, your suggested indexes are more sensible than the ones I guessed without knowing what your query patterns were.

Comment: Also, adding 2 indexes on a small table like this will be costly?

Comment: It's in the 'grey range'.  If the table was under 100 rows, the indexes would probably not be worth the trouble.  If the table was in the millions of rows, they would be worth it.  If the table is in the thousands, the chances are the index will be beneficial.  One option to consider is including `id` as the third column in the index.  Then the query engine can use an index-only search, rather than having to read the index and the data pages.  (With a small table and no indexes, you'd be doing a sequential scan over one or two pages, which is faster than reading index pages and data pages.)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE CLUSTER INDEX clusidx ON hitlist(hitlisted_date,deleted_date);
CREATE         INDEX ddatidx ON hitlist(deleted_date);
```

If the table has few rows, it might not even be worth indexing the columns, but with many rows yes. Since you only have 3 columns in this table, then indexing wont be a problem with a huge numbers of rows.

*Example:*

I have a static readonly table with 13 VARCHAR columns and 2 DATE columns.

rowlength = 557, nrows = 12,398,250.

Indexing on 7 separate columns, since there are no frequent queries involving multiple columns, but if one particular combo of columns is frequently queried, then create a composite column index for those queries.

Comment: The `hdaidx` is not going to pay its way.

Comment: Yes; the cluster index can be used for anything that hdaidx can be used for. If there are going to be vast ranges of deleted dates for any given hitlisted date, then it might sometimes be better to have the single column index, but it would be fairly unusual for it to be beneficial.  If the table is dynamic (lots of activity), then the extra index may cost more on update than it saves on select; if the table is almost static (very little activity), then the opposite may be true.  It is unlikely the hitlisted date can be a unique index; if it could, there might be other reasons for having it.